# ParametricPlot for phase field error (case: Predator-Prey Model)

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, parametric-functions, modeling

so I have a task that need to draw a phase field of predator-prey model, but first I tried my lecturer's coding:

```
p1 = VectorPlot[{x(1-y), 0.3*y(x-1)}, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 3}];
ode1[x0_, y0_] := NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] (1-y[t]), y'[t] == 0.3*y[t] (x[t]-1), x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, 
{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 100}];
sol[1] = ode1[1, 2];
sol[2] = ode1[1, 3];
sol[3] = ode1[1, 1.2];
p2 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol[i], {i, 3}], {t, 0, 100}], 
     PlotRange→{{0, 6}, {0, 3}}, PlotPoints→100, AxesLabel→{"x", "y"}];
Show[{p1, p2}, PlotRange→{{0, 6}, {0, 3}}, AxesLabel→{"x", "y"}, Axes→True]
```

then there's an error:

```
ParametricPlot::nonopt: Options expected (instead of AxesLabel→{x,y}) beyond position 3 in
ParametricPlot[<<1>>, {t,0,100}, PlotRange→{{0,6},{0,3}}, PlotPoints→100,AxesLabel→{x,y}].
An option must be a rule or a list of rules.
```

I truly have no idea how to fix this... can someone help me?

Comment: `→` is not the same as `->` or `\[Rule]`. Use one of the latter two instead.

Comment: You should also be using `FrameLabel` rather than `AxesLabel`

Comment: @MichaelE2 im sorry i didnt mean to use the arrow symbol because im new here (thought i didnt like how it looks \[RightArrow]), thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 6):

With a couple of changes:

```
p1 = VectorPlot[{x (1 - y), 0.3*y (x - 1)}, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 3}];
ode1[x0_, y0_] := 
  NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] (1 - y[t]), y'[t] == 0.3*y[t] (x[t] - 1), 
    x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 100}];
sol[1] = ode1[1, 2];
sol[2] = ode1[1, 3];
sol[3] = ode1[1, 1.2];
funs[t_] == Table[{x[t], y[t]} /. Flatten[sol[i]], {i, 3}];
p2 = ParametricPlot[funs, {t, 0, 100}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}];
Show[{p1, p2}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

- Using `ParametricNDSolveValue` etc.

```
Clear[p1, sol, p2];
p1 = VectorPlot[{x (1 - y), 0.3*y (x - 1)}, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 3}];
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == x[t] (1 - y[t]), 
    y'[t] == 0.3*y[t] (x[t] - 1), x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x[t], 
    y[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, {x0, y0}];
p2 = ParametricPlot[{sol[1, 2], sol[1, 3], sol[1, 1.2]}, {t, 0, 
    100}];
Show[p1, p2, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

- Using `StreamPlot`.

```
Clear[vectorfield, p1, p2];
vectorfield = {x (1 - y), 0.3*y (x - 1)};
p1 = VectorPlot[vectorfield, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 3}];
p2 = StreamPlot[vectorfield, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 3}, 
   StreamScale -> None, 
   StreamPoints -> {{{{1, 2}, Blue}, {{1, 3}, Brown}, {{1, 1.2}, 
       Green}}}, StreamColorFunction -> None, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
Show[p1, p2, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]